# local git check-ins -- hide from main repository?

Tags: git

I thought I remembered reading somewhere a way to do this, but I can't find it.

I'm working locally, on a local branch even, and I'm checking in as needed, or daily or whatever.  When I get the code to the point where I want to push it to the main repository, is there a way to just push the file as is, and not push all of the history?  Or when I merge from a branch back to main, can I not merge the history?

Are these even good ideas?  Thanks for the help -- still learning, here!

joe

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could merge your changes as a single commit on the main branch:

```
$ git checkout main
$ git merge --squash local
```

That discards all of your local history, of course. All in all that is not something I would do. Instead, if you’re worried about embarrassing or compromising commits in your local history, use `git rebase` to rewrite your local history; afterward, perform a normal merge and push out your cleaned-up local history as well.

Edit/clarification: an *interactive* rebase will allow you to easily remove or "squash" commits in your history:

```
$ git checkout local
$ git rebase -i main
```